# Fetching 'title' from WP REST API with React

Tags: reactjs, fetch, undefined, typeerror, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to fetch some data from the Wordpress REST API to render it in my React App. For example 'title', 'date' and 'content'. Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props){
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     title: {},
     date: "",
     content: {}
   };
 }

 componentDidMount() {
       return fetch(`https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100`)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {
         const { title, date, content } = responseJson;
         this.setState({ title, date, content });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error);
       });
 }

 render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <h1> {this.state.title.rendered} </h1>
        <h3> {this.state.date} </h3>
        <p> {this.state.content.rendered} </p>
      </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

But this gives me the following error for both 'title' and 'content':

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to fix this error?

Comment: Can you log values from `const { title, date, content } = responseJson;`? Looks like undefined. Not just while initial rendering, but check between refreshes as well.

Comment: Yes, you are correct – 'responseJson' values are 'undefined' as well. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I guess your API call is missing the authentication values. Let's check that.

Comment: I put a fake domain here. But original link is working correctly and by following it I can see the whole JSON data I need. It works without any authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fixed the issue:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    return fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
      this.setState({
        posts: posts,
      });
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.posts.map(item => (
              <div key={item.id}>
              <h1>
                  {item.title.rendered}
              </h1>
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.content.rendered }}>
              </p>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **accessing WordPress API requires authentication parameters**, please verify that.
Example:

```
Request: GET https://<domain-name>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
Header: Authorization : Bearer <token>
```

You run the risk of replacing your state properties with `undefined` from the fetch API call.

Try this instead. Will help catch the undefined and put a fallback content instead.

```js
this.setState({
    date,
    title: title || {rendered: false}, 
    content: content || {rendered: false}
});
```

Comment: I tried this to check what I get after each step: `const { title, date, content } = responseJson; console.log(responseJson);  this.setState({ date, title: title || {rendered: false}, content: content || {rendered: false} }); console.log(responseJson);` and it logs all JSON data that it fetches from the API. And there is no more error mentioned originally but it doesn't render anything – just blank page.